# How to make Zend_JSON creating objects rather than arrays

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I use zend's JSON helper, and I have a problem... When I use this code :

```
$this->_helper->json(array(1 => "value 1", 2 => "value 2"));
```

I get an object:

```
{1: "value 1", 2: "value 2" }
```

But if the keys are a sequence beginning by "0", I get an array. For exemple, with :

```
$this->_helper->json(array(0 => "value 0", 1 => "value 1"));
```

I get an array:

```
["value 0", "value 1"]
```

How can I do to get an object every time I use this method ? (I want the result `{0: "value 0", 1: "value 1" }` in the second example).

Comment: try  $this->_helper->json((object)array(0 => "value 0", 1 => "value 1"));

Comment: Thanks. However, it works for simple objects, but not in the case of nested objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force it to be an object

```
<?php
$arr = array(1 => "value 1", 2 => "value 2");

$x = json_encode($arr);
var_dump($x);

//use this to force to be an object
$y = json_encode(array(0 => "value 1", 1 => "value 2"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
var_dump($y);

// how it is
$z = json_encode(array(0 => "value1", 1 => "value 2" ));
var_dump($z);
?>
```

gives

```
string(29) "{"1":"value 1","2":"value 2"}"
string(29) "{"0":"value 1","1":"value 2"}"
string(20) "["value1","value 2"]"
```

Comment: Ok, it works! I've been stuck on Zend... But native php seems to be doing the job ^^. Thanks